# Realistic deadlock example in CUDA/OpenCL

Tags: synchronization, cuda, parallel-processing, opencl, simd

For a tutorial I'm writing, I'm looking for a "realistic" and simple example of a deadlock caused by ignorance of SIMT / SIMD.

I came up with this snippet, which seems to be a good example.

Any input would be appreciated.

```
…
int x = threadID / 2;
if (threadID > x) {
    value[threadID] = 42;
    barrier();
    }
else {
    value2[threadID/2] = 13
    barrier();
}
result = value[threadID/2] + value2[threadID/2];
```

*I know, it is neither proper CUDA C nor OpenCL C.*

Comment: It seems too complicated to be an example and rather simple for a "realistic" one. I would use only `get_local_id(0) > constant` in the condition and replace the "business code" (assignment) with comments `/* do some stuff */` and `/* do another stuff */`.
Nevertheless, I think StackOverflow is not the best place for discussion, it's a place for questions and answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple deadlock that is actually easy to catch by the novice CUDA programmer is when one tries to implement a critical section for a single thread, that should ultimately be performed by all threads. It goes more-or-less like this:

```
__global__ kernel() {
  __shared__ int semaphore;
  semaphore=0;
  __syncthreads();
  while (true) {
    int prev=atomicCAS(&semaphore,0,1);
    if (prev==0) {
      //critical section
      semaphore=0;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The `atomicCAS` instruction ensures that exaclty one thread gets 0 assigned to prev, while all others get 1. When that one thread finishes its critical section, it sets the semaphore back to 0 so that other threads have a chance to enter the critical section.

The problem is, that while 1 thread gets prev=0, 31 threads, belonging to the same SIMD unit get a value 1. At the if-statement CUDA scheduler puts that single thread on-hold (masks it out) and let other 31-threads continue their work. In normal circumstances it is a good strategy, but in this particular case you end up with 1 critical-section thread that is never executed and 31 threads waiting for infinity. Deadlock.

Also note, the existence of `break` which leads the control flow outside of the `while` loop. If you ommit the break instruction and have some more operations after the if-block that are supposed to be executed by all threads, it may actually help the scheduler avoid the deadlock.

Regarding your example given in the question: in CUDA it is explicitly forbidden to put `__syncthreads()` in a SIMD-diverging code. The compiler won't catch it but the manual says about "undefined behaviour". In practice, on pre-Fermi devices, all `__syncthreads()` are seen as the same barriers. With that assumtion, your code would actually terminate without an error. One should *not* rely on this behaviour though.