# __syncthreads() Deadlock

Tags: c++, cuda

Will __syncthreads() cause a dead lock if only some threads execute it?

i have a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void Kernel(int N,int *a)
{
    if(threadIdx.x<N)
    {
      for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
       {
        a[threadIdx.x]= //Some calculation using a and i
        __syncthreads()
       }
    }
}
```

if the number of threads in the block is greater than N, then some threads will not execute the code. will this cause a deadlock?
if yes, then how can i modify the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *not* use `__syncthreads()` in a divergent code. Its behaviour in such circumstances is undefined.

`__syncthreads()` may appear in a conditional branch only if you are sure, this branch will be evaluated uniformly, in the same way, by all threads in a block (either all, or no threads from a block take the branch).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, kernels can't deadlock; they can only time out.  But yes, what you are describing is real and can happen.  The issue has actually been discussed before, for example: [Realistic deadlock example in CUDA/OpenCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426793/realistic-deadlock-example-in-cuda-opencl)

Comment: They CAN deadlock, and non-display CUDA devices have no watchdog timer, therefore they will not time out if they deadlock in that case.