# CUDA: same code different results on Quadro 3000M and Tesla C1060

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

the code pointed by the below link works on Tesla C1060 but does not work on my mobile workstation with a Quadro 3000M.

This is mainly what the code does:

http://pastebin.com/9JKUMwZ4

The execution on the Quadro 3000M simply skips the kernel and outputs a blanck image in few ms.
The execution on the Tesla C1060 outputs a processed image in (say) 100 s. The weird thing is that in the last days also the execution on the c1060 appeared rather unpredictable (sometimes skipping the kernel, sometimes outputting weird numbers as -10^12, ..). I do not understand this behaviour.
Could it be a driver version problem?

Thank you in advance for helping.

ps. both machines on ubuntu 11.10

```
Quadro 3000M  ---> Cuda compilation tools, release 4.1, V0.2.1221
Tesla C1060   ---> Cuda compilation tools, release 4.1, V0.2.1221
```

EDIT: the problem is very likely linked to the different GPU architectures of my 2 cards.

Comment: Q3000m typically has 2GB, C1060 has more.  How much GPU memory are you allocating?  Also you should do error checking on your kernel calls.  Are you running X on the Q3000M?

Comment: 1)cudaMemGetInfo(&f, &t) before the kernel gives free=1727807488, total= 2147024896. 2) if I place some errorChecks I get the error @line 75 : CUDA Runtime API error 4: unspecified launch failure. 3) yes, I'm running X, I'll try to run the code with X disabled. Thank you

Comment: The Quadro 3000M is a Fermi part. It has improved memory protection compared to the GT200 based C1060. It is likely that your code has out of bounds access somewhere which causes the code to fail on the Fermi device. Try running your code with cuda-memcheck and see what it reports.

Comment: I get indeed misaligned addresses http://pastebin.com/VF4YeKvA. It is weird that this code is working differently in different GPU generations, I suppose I should point my attention at kernel code where I access *src (line 33) http://pastebin.com/E60Rvu9j

Answer (score 1):

You have `__syncthreads()` inside `if` statement. This is not allowed an can cause deadlocks.

See [__syncthreads() Deadlock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6476613/56875) post.

Cuda-memcheck and debugger are the best toosl to investigate such and other issues.

Comment: I commented out __syncthreads() but unfortunately it did not work. As you also suggested I run cuda-memcheck and got pastebin.com/VF4YeKvA. As pointed out in my last comment, the problem resides in *src access. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed and make this code safe across different GPU generations?

Comment: Your kernel accesses a pointer which is not correctly aligned for the size of variable that you read. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832846/56875 Either align the pointer or read 1 byte. Please also include the source of gpuContrastKernel2

Comment: here is the kernel http://pastebin.com/RVpEjzNS. Thank you for your suggestions, now I focus on the pointer and let you know.